# Why the object array can be initialized only using the default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    A(int _x) : x(_x) {}
private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    A a[100](1); //compile error
    A ptr = new A[100](1); // compile error
    return 0;
}
```

As we know, the sample code will encounter compile error, because an object array can be initialized only by default constructor.

Why cannot an object be initialized using a constructor with parameter?

I recently read the book *Inside the C++ Object Model*. As the book mentioned, when initializing an object array, the process will call a function (named `vec_new` in cfront 2.0) which accepts a constructor pointer and call the constructor without any arguments. It means the function can only call the default constructor, so an object array can be initialized only using the default constructor.

But, why does the compiler use `vec_new` to initialize an object array?

If the compiler does not call the `vec_new`, it can expand the code to initialize all the objects in an array like the sample code:

```
int main()
{
    A ptr = new A[100](1);
    ////// expanded code, I suppose
    /** 1. allocate memory to ptr
    *   2. constuct 100 object respectively
    *   int i = 0;
    *   char *tmp_ptr = (char *)ptr;
    *   while(i++ < 100) {
    *      tmp_ptr = A::A(tmp_ptr, 1);
           tmp_ptr += sizeof(A);
        }
    */
    return 0;
}
```

I confuse that if a compiler implement "initializing an object array using constructor with arguments"?

Comment: "Why cannot an object be initialized using a constructor with parameter?" It can be. You just need different syntax.

Comment: Code like such `A ptr = new A[100](1);` should be replaced by `std::vector<A> v(100, A(1));`.

Comment: `A arr1[5]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` or `A arr2[2]{A(), A(10)};`

Comment: Another example of why dynamic arrays are a misfeature in C++ and should never be used.

Comment: Note that `<..>` is parsed as an HTML tag outside of code blocks / inline code. The text in between might disappear.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for kindly reply :). How the compiler expand the code to initialize all elements? and an exception may be caused while initializing front elements, then how the compiler handle this problem ?Is this a new feature introduced in C++11?

Comment: I just thought it might work and it worked, so I don't know how exactly it works. I suggest you to look into the standart or test yourself.